# How to send two inputs with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

ok, i have these two input fields where a user puts in two twitter names. When the submit button is pressed, both names should be send to a .php file with the POST method that checks if both usernames exsist on twitter.

Sending and receiving the answer for one value already works, but how can i also add the second? I already have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkUsername()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tu.php',
        **data: {'user1' : $('#user1').val() },** //how to append user2?
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#uitslag').html(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            $('#user1text').html(data['user1']);
            $('#user2text').html(data['user2']);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

the fields in the form:

```
    <td><input type="text" name="user1" id="user1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="user2" id="user2" /></td>
```

and this is how the values should be able to be cathed in the .php:

```
$user1 = $_POST['user1'];
$user2 = $_POST['user2'];
```

So the question really is: how can I append the second username to the above jQuery POST function?

p.s. I am starting with javascript and jQuery, how do you guys work with this as no error messages are shown ever.. is there an environment/programm where I get debugging help with javascript?

Comment: Regarding your last question, firefox + firebug plug-in is pretty much the standard for javascript development, as far as I know.

Comment: also google chrome dev tools are very usefull ind debugging javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple enough extension-- just follow the same pattern.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkUsername()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tu.php',
        data: {
            'user1' : $('#user1').val(),
            'user2' : $('#user2').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#uitslag').html(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            $('#user1text').html(data['user1']);
            $('#user2text').html(data['user2']);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

That said, jQuery does also have a `.serialize()` function that you could apply on the containing form, which automatically serializes the whole form. This could prove useful for you.

---

**EDIT:** It's worth mentioning that the jQuery selectors above look on the **id** for the name "user1" (etc.), whereas the PHP script expects the form elements' **name** to be "user1" (etc.). Here you have them as the same thing.

A more reliable jQuery selector that would allow you to always use the name in both jQuery and PHP is simply to use an attribute selector in jQuery:

```
$('input[name="user1"]').val()
```

This will catch any `<input>` element with the `name` attribute set to "user1".

Comment: thanks, i thought i tried your solution and it wasn't working, must have missed a comma or somethign, thanks! With regars to your id/name comment, thanks, have been using both all the time, will switch to using one now!

Comment: @Javaaaa: You don't HAVE to, it just will save you problems later. Your current way will always work AS LONG AS your ID and Name are the same for all your form fields. But if you use the name attribute in jQuery, then you can use whatever IDs you want in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
data: {
     'user1' : $('#user1').val(), 
     'user2' : $('#user2').val()
},
```

Comment: damn, thanks this works! This was my first try to make it work but I guess some comma was missing or something!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Your code would look something like this:

```
function checkUsername()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tu.php',
        data: $("#your_form").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#uitslag').html(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            $('#user1text').html(data['user1']);
            $('#user2text').html(data['user2']);
        }
    });
}
```

If you're sure you don't want serialize you could try this:

```
data: {'user1' : $('#user1').val(), 'user2' : $('#user2').val() }
```

As for your PS, check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Webkit developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html).

Comment: Thank you too for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't even need the serialize function. If you just select your form, all form elements will be passed. This way if you just add another form element, like another textbox, it will all be passed in your ajax call.

```
function checkUsername()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tu.php',
        data: $("#your_form"),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#uitslag').html(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            $('#user1text').html(data['user1']);
            $('#user2text').html(data['user2']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also i noticed how you are using the json object begin return. Based on your code, on success you will get and object passed in named data. That object has a number of properties you can access. So if user1 is a properties all you need to write is data.user1 or data.user2 and you will be able to access that value in the object. It's already serialized for you because you passed in dataType:"json"